# Oracle insert performs too long

Tags: oracle, insert, locking

I'm confused about time Oracle 10g XE performs insert. I implemented bulk insert from xml file into several tables with programmatical transaction managment. Why one insert performs in a moment and another more than 10 minutes! I can't wait more and stop it. I think there's something more complex I have not payed attention yet.

Update:

I found lock using Monitor.

```
Waits     
Event   enq: TX - row lock contention
name|mode   1415053316
usnusnusnusn<<16 | slot 327711
sequence    162

SQL   
INSERT INTO ESKD$SERVICESET (ID, TOUR_ID, CURRENCY_ID) VALUES (9, 9, 1)
```

What does it mean and how should I resolve it?

Comment: you problem description is _very_ vague. please be more clear about what is long, and what is fast, and in what context (are you using transactions? bulk insert? impdp? ...)

Comment: Please show some of the code you're using for the insert. And describe what you call "programmatical transaction management". How much data (number of inserted rows) are we talking about? What language are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: Very vague indeed. Many possible reasons for bad performance: complex triggers on some of the tables, open transactions by other users, current size of the tables in which data is inserted, present indexes on the tables. And many many more...

Comment: I found lock. Pls see updated question.

Comment: Possibly that there is another transaction that is modifying records of this table and this transaction never got committed or rolled back.

Comment: How many sessions are concurrently modifying the same tables? Since it's an insert, the conflict cannot be directly on the inserted row but is probably in a unique constraint index or in a primary key index of a referenced table.

Comment: what is " programmatical transaction managment" <-- this is generally a very bad idea and should be left to the database unless you are EXTREMELY proficient and usurping the DB's transactions for a very specific reason.

Comment: I mean TransactionStatus, manual commit(status) and rollback(status) as "programmatical transaction managment". The algorithm is to insert some data in different short transactions and some part of data in more long play transaction. First part of data is some kind of "catalog" data. I think problem is in transaction managment. In previous version data is uploading in one transaction and that was ok.

Comment: Long running transactions are fine in isolation. Combining them with short transactions is the killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TX- Enqueues are well known and a quick google will give you a clear [answer](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/05/what-is-enq-tx-row-lock-contention.html).

From that article:

> 1) Waits for TX in mode 6 occurs when a session is waiting for a row level lock that is already held by another session. This occurs when one user is updating or deleting a row, which another session wishes to update or delete. This type of TX enqueue wait corresponds to the wait event enq: TX - row lock contention.

If you have lots of simultaneous inserts and updates to a table you want each transaction to be a short as possible. Get in, get out... the longer things sit in between, the longer the delays for OTHER transactions.

PURE GUESS:

I have a feeling that your mention of "programmatical transaction managment" is that you're trying to use a table like a QUEUE. Inserting a start record, updating it frequently to change the status and then deleting the 'finished' ones. That is always trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This question will be really hard to answer with so little specific information.  All that I can tell you is why this could be.

If you are doing an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` bulk insert then perhaps your `SELECT` query is performing poorly.  There may be a large number of table joins, innefficient use of inline views and other resources that may be negatively impacting the performance of your `INSERT`.

Try executing your `SELECT` query in an Explain Plan to see how the Optimizer is deriving the plan and to evaluation the COST of the query.

The other thing that you mentioned was a possible lock.  This could be the case however you will need to analyze this with the OEM tool to tell for sure.

Another thing to consider may be that you do not have indexes on your tables OR the statistics on these tables may be out of date.  Out of date statistics can GREATLY impact the performance of queries on large tables.

Answer (score 0):

see sites.google.com/site/embtdbo/wait-event-documentation/oracle-enqueues

The locking wait indicates a conflict that could easily be the cause of your performance issues. On the surface it looks likely that the problem is inserting a duplicate key value while the first insert of that key value had not yet committed. The lock you see "enq: TX - row lock contention"  happens because one session is trying to modify uncommited data from another session. There are 4 common reasons for this particular lock wait event:

1. update/delete of the same row

   inserting the same uniq key

   modifying the same bitmap index chunk

   deleting/updating a parent value to a foreign key

We can eliminate the first and last case are you are doing an insert.
You should be able to identify the 2nd if you have no bitmap indexes involved. If you have bitmap indexes involved and you have uniq keys involved then you could investigate easily if you had Active Session History (ASH) data, but unfortunately Oracle XE doesn't. On the other hand you can collected it yourself with S-ASH, see : http://ashmasters.com/ash-simulation/ .  With ASH or S-ASH you can run a query like

```
col event for a22
col block_type for a18
col objn for a18
col otype for a10
col fn for 99
col sid for 9999
col bsid for 9999
col lm for 99
col p3 for 99999
col blockn for 99999
select
       to_char(sample_time,'HH:MI') st,
       substr(event,0,20) event,
       ash.session_id sid,
       mod(ash.p1,16)  lm,
       ash.p2,
       ash.p3, 
       nvl(o.object_name,ash.current_obj#) objn,
       substr(o.object_type,0,10) otype,
       CURRENT_FILE# fn,
       CURRENT_BLOCK# blockn, 
       ash.SQL_ID,
       BLOCKING_SESSION bsid
       --,ash.xid
from v$active_session_history ash,
      all_objects o
where event like 'enq: TX %'
   and o.object_id (+)= ash.CURRENT_OBJ#
Order by sample_time
/
```

Which would output something like:

```
ST    EVENT                  SID  LM     P2   P3 OBJ   OTYPE  FN BLOCKN SQL_ID         BSID
10:41 enq: TX - row lock c   143   4 966081 4598 I1    INDEX   0      0 azav296xxqcjx   144
10:41 enq: TX - row lock c   143   4 966081 4598 I1    INDEX   0      0 azav296xxqcjx   144
10:41 enq: TX - row lock c   143   4 966081 4598 I1    INDEX   0      0 azav296xxqcjx   144
10:41 enq: TX - row lock c   143   4 966081 4598 I1    INDEX   0      0 azav296xxqcjx   144
```

showing that the object name "OBJ" and the object type "OTYPE" with the contention and that the type is an INDEX.  From there you could look up the type of INDEX to verify that it is bitmap.
IF the problem is a bitmap index, then you should probably re-evaluate using bitmap indexes or revisit the way that data is loaded and/or modify to reduce conflicts.

If the problem isn't BITMAP indexes, then it's trying to insert a duplicate key. Some other process had inserted the same key value and not yet committed. Then your process tries to insert the same key value and has to wait for the first session to commit or rollback.

For more information see this link:  lock waits

Answer (score 0):

It means, your sequence cache is to small. Increase it.